# Opencart Force login when see Cart Page?

Tags: php, opencart

There are a number of pages that require a customer to log in to view them. How would I do this for the cart page `/index.php?route=checkout/cart`

Comment: **So any body can not see Shipping Charges and Tax without login**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean you want to have a customer login if they go to the cart page correct? If so, here's how you do it. Open `/catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php` and find this line

```
public function index() {
```

Below this line, add the following code

```
    if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $this->session->data['redirect'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart', '', 'SSL');

        $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL')); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for 2.xx, you need add `response->redirect()` instead of `redirect()`

like this

```
if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $this->session->data['redirect'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart', '', 'SSL');

        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL')); 
    }
```