# Opencart Force Login

Tags: redirect, authentication, opencart

I would like to redirect a customer to the login page if they are not logged in from any page on the site. I am trying to limit access to a subdomain to a specific customer group and the rest of my code works.

If I use the following code on home.tpl it works

```
 if (!$logged) { 
        $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
    }
```

but if I put it in the header (so it will react for every page), I get a redirect loop because it will try to redirect the actual login page to itself.

Is there a way to correctly say:

```
if ($this->url->link != 'account/login') {
    $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Matt

Comment: Just so you know my code for the rest is:<?php 

 if (!$logged) { 
  $this-> $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
 } else if  ( $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId() == '1' ) { 
  $this->customer->logout();
  $this->redirect("URL");
 }

?>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opencart Force login when see Cart Page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074123/opencart-force-login-when-see-cart-page)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to check the store is the subdomain one as well, you should use code something like this

```
// Check store ID against subdomain store id value
if($this->config->get('config_store_id') == 123) {

    // Check customer isn't logged in
    if(!$this->customer->isLogged()) {

        // Redirect if route isn't account/login
        if(empty($this->request->get['route']) || $this->request->get['route'] != 'account/login') {
            $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other possibility is to create a *preAction* - e.g. like maintenance mode. I have used this once and I think this is much cleaner solution than implementing it in the view **template** (so it follows the MVC pattern - logic is done in controller, view is only for presenting the data and gathering input from user).

Create a class `catalog/controller/common/login.php`

```php
class ControllerCommonLogin extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        if($this->config->get('config_store_id') == 1) { // if desired store, continue checking

            if(!$this->customer->isLogged()) { // Check user isn't logged in
                if(empty($this->request->get['route']) || $this->request->get['route'] != 'account/login') { // Redirect if route isn't account/login
                    $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then open up `index.php` (frontend one) and find line:

```php
// Maintenance Mode
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/maintenance'));
```

and **after** add this:

```php
// Login needed pre-action
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/login'));
```

You should be done.

Comment: +1 - This should be done as a pre action as is the case in the admin area

Comment: For Opencart 2.0 replace redirect line with $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/login'));

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a condition like:

```
 if($this->config->get('config_store_id') == 1) { //Add your subdomain store id, if you want to limit the condition for a subdomain. 

      if( (!isset($this->request->get['route']) || $this->request->get['route'] != 'account/login' ) && (!$this->customer->isLogged()) ){
         $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
      }
 }
```

`$this->request->get['route']` - this will get you the current page path.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking if you are already on the login page, if so don't run code. You can check this if your on a page called login.php. Simple and clean solution