# Removing opencart registration and new customer field (but NOT the login field)

Tags: templates, e-commerce, opencart

I have 2 question about opencart, I would really, really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

1) I want to taking off the new customer registration from the log in area, because I would like to create my own customers I do not want them to create their own account with my site.

2) I want my customers to log in before any content of the page appears for them.

And I'm using opencart v1.5.6 and the default template.

Please please please help.

Comment: @Sankar V 

I have 2 problems now again first I can not, 1) I can not find this on this file (catalog/controller/account/login.php/)  ( <div class="left">
  <h2><?php echo $text_new_customer; ?></h2>
  <div class="content">
    <p><b><?php echo $text_register; ?></b></p>
    <p><?php echo $text_register_account; ?></p>
    <a href="<?php echo $register; ?>" class="button"><?php echo $button_continue; ?></a></div>
</div> /)

Comment: 2) under what line do I add this on [catalog/controller/common/header.php] file (code)if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) { $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL')); } (/code)

Comment: please find my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below condition in your `catalog/controller/common/header.php` file (before `if (isset($this->session->data['error']) && !empty($this->session->data['error'])) {`.`).

```
if (!$this->customer->isLogged() && (!isset($this->request->get['route']) || $this->request->get['route'] != 'account/login' )) { 
    $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
}
```

Remove the below section of code from your `catalog/controller/account/login.tpl` file.

```
<div class="left">
  <h2><?php echo $text_new_customer; ?></h2>
  <div class="content">
    <p><b><?php echo $text_register; ?></b></p>
    <p><?php echo $text_register_account; ?></p>
    <a href="<?php echo $register; ?>" class="button"><?php echo $button_continue; ?></a></div>
</div>
```

Also update the below code in `catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl`

```
<div id="welcome">
<?php if (!$logged) { ?>
<?php echo $text_welcome; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php echo $text_logged; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

to --->

```
<div id="welcome">
<?php if (!$logged) { ?>

<?php } else { ?>
<?php echo $text_logged; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Have a nice day!!

Comment: please see if you can help any further because I'm back to square one.

Comment: please find my updated answer. it was `.php` instead of `.tpl`. Addeed the position of first `if` condition also.

Comment: thank you so much for the help once again, but I can not find .tpl on this (catalog/controller/account/login.tpl) directory there are all .php. but I went and changed it on a different directory (catalog/view/theme/default/template/account/login.tpl). now when I open the page it comes with this error (Make sure the web address) does not open the page at all.

Comment: I'm sorry I wanted to ask one more question if you could help. At the very top of the page under the search box there is this (Welcome visitor you can login or **create an account**.) where it say  create an account how can I remove that also.

Comment: I removed this (Welcome visitor you can login or **create an account**.) don't worry about this one, and I also found the problem why the page isn't loading up. it is the first code that is the problem ('if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) { 
    $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
}') and the other codes that you have mentioned worked like magic! thank you so much could you please have a looked at the first code see if that can be fixed. The problem with that is when I put that code the page doesn't load at all. Thanks

Comment: Please find my updated answer. `if` condition updated

Comment: What happens now if I come to Your shop and go directly to URL `http://yourprivateshop.com/index.php?route=account/register`??? **I do not like *un-finished* or *half-* solutions**...

Comment: @shadyyx The redirect condition is written in header controller, so any page(including register page) other than the login page gets redirected to login page.

Comment: Also please let me know if you have a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be good if the user willing to register will get some message that the registration is locked and that the user should contact You for the registration request. It wouldn't be a good solution if You just remove the *register* links as users then may think that they can shop only as a guests so they will lose their time on Your store just to find out that they cannot...

The second part has a solution (or more) here: [Opencart Force Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357962/opencart-force-login).

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but I want only make my own clients it will not be open for public so I need to make it for all my clients, its a private site. Once again thank you for the help