# Opencart Force login and register

Tags: redirect, authentication, opencart

I used the solution of shadyyx [like on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20371909)

It works great.

But where in the code I should change something when I want to exclude the registration page?
Otherwise customers cannot register because they get redirected to the login page...

```
class ControllerCommonLogin extends Controller {

public function index() {
    if($this->config->get('config_store_id') == 4) { // if desired store, continue checking

        if(!$this->user->isLogged()) { // Check user isn't logged in
            if(empty($this->request->get['route']) || $this->request->get['route'] != 'account/login') { // Redirect if route isn't account/login
                $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opencart Force Login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357962/opencart-force-login)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead for the controller code

```
Class ControllerCommonLogin extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        if($this->config->get('config_store_id') == 1) { // if desired store, continue checking
            $skip = array(
                'account/login',
                'account/register',
            );

            $route = empty($this->request->get['route']) ? 'common/home' : $this->request->get['route'];

            if(!$this->customer->isLogged()) { // Check user isn't logged in
                if(!in_array($route, $skip)) { // Redirect if route isn't account/login
                    $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply! but now i get the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function isLogged() on a non-object in /public_html/catalog/controller/common/login.php on line 13

Comment: @Bennieb see above - the original answer appears to be using admin code

Comment: it works :) thanks, but now I get an error when I visit the registration page. Without the redirection or on the other sites of the multishop it is no problem. The error is: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
OK (or you can visit http://goo.gl/7EeNOQ )

Comment: That's not anything to do with this

Comment: But it's an error about account/login while i'm on the account/register page?